# How to config the heroku.yml to use the Heroku PostgreSQL addon?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, heroku, continuous-deployment

What I currently I do is to deploy my Django application to Heroku through [Building Docker Images with heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml).
The app is built well, but it cannot connect to the database, because of the host is not configured correctly. My `heroku.yml` config is

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: Django-BaaS.settings_docker
release:
  command:
    - python manage.py migrate
  image: web
run:
  web: gunicorn Django-BaaS.wsgi
```

My `settings_docker` is

```
from .settings_base import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'psql',
        'HOST': 'DATABASE',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

My understanding is that `heroku.yml` is a file which is similar to `docker-compose.yml` so I tried to use `DATABASE` as the `HOST` name (and I tried to use `localhost`), but it looks like that both are not correct way to connect the database.

I seek some help to correct my config or setting files and how to use the PostgreSQL addon on heroku's docker CD pipeline. I am stuck here for a while. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. There are 2 mistakes I made.

1. `heroku.yml` is like `docker-compose.yml`, but between `addons` in `setup` and `build`, there is no `bridge`. Keyword **as** is not equal to **container_name**.
2. The container (in the case it is web), it can still directly access the `psql addon`, but the access url it is not `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` (which will try to visit the container itself), it is a dynamic value stored in `environment variable`.

### How to make it work

The direct way is using [dj_database_url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url), update the db setting to,

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.parse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
```

The better way is to use [django_heroku](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku), update the setting to,

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

### References

- [Django-BaaS the project I am working on](https://github.com/pypurecms/Django-BaaS/blob/config-cd/Django-BaaS/settings_heroku.py)
- [dj-databse-url github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url)
- [Deploying Python and Django Apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python)
- [How to serve django static files on heroku with gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482659/how-to-serve-django-static-files-on-heroku-with-gunicorn)